# c++ libcurl progress callback with download not working

Tags: c++, progress-bar, libcurl

I'm using curl for uploads and downloads and also try to include the provided progress bar from curl. I managed to get the progress bar working when uploading files, but unfortunately the callback function only receives 0 values on the download.

Here are the options that are set for the download:

```
::curl_easy_reset( m_pimpl->curl ) ;
::curl_easy_setopt( m_pimpl->curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,  0L ) ;
::curl_easy_setopt( m_pimpl->curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,  0L ) ;
::curl_easy_setopt( m_pimpl->curl, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION,  &CurlAgent::HeaderCallback ) ;
::curl_easy_setopt( m_pimpl->curl, CURLOPT_HEADERDATA,      this ) ;
::curl_easy_setopt( m_pimpl->curl, CURLOPT_HEADER,          0L ) ;
::curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, method.c_str() ); // "GET" in download

::curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER,   error ) ;
::curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL,           url.c_str());
::curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &CurlAgent::Receive ) ;
::curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA,     this ) ;

//setting the progress callback function
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 0L);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_XFERINFOFUNCTION, progress_callback);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_XFERINFODATA, this);

CURLcode curl_code = ::curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

ANd this is the callback used for the progress bar:

```
static int progress_callback(void *ptr,   curl_off_t TotalDownloadSize,   curl_off_t finishedDownloadSize,   curl_off_t TotalToUpload,   curl_off_t NowUploaded) {

    curl_off_t processed = (TotalDownloadSize > TotalToUpload) ? finishedDownloadSize : NowUploaded;
    curl_off_t total = (TotalDownloadSize > TotalToUpload) ? TotalDownloadSize : TotalToUpload;

    ...

    return 0;
}
```

As mentioned when I perform uploads of files the parameters `TotalToUpload` and `NowUploaded` contain the correct values. But when downloading all four parameters contain `0`!?
Do I have to set another option when downloading files to receive the correct sizes?

**Alternative solution**

I found an alternative solution, buy using another request that delivers information about the files on the drive which also contains the file size. 
In the set callback write function

```
   ::curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &CurlAgent::Receive )
```

the current downloaded size is given as parameter with which it is then possible to create the progress bar.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/) is also the documentation of the used service and the requests:

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), including a real URL, that demonstrates this? What kind of URL are you requesting? HTTP? FTP? What is `method` set to? If you are retrieving an HTTP url, and setting `method` to `"GET"` then you are not supposed to be using `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` like that at all, you are supposed to use `CURLOPT_HTTPGET` instead.

Comment: I'm using it in combination with downloading files from Google drive so to provide a working example is difficult...
I tried to set the `CURLOPT_HTTPGET` flag instead but it doesn't make a difference

Comment: Please provide a MCVE (emphasis on **minimal**) for a public url that demonstrates the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Per the libcurl documentation:

[CURLOPT_XFERINFOFUNCTION explained](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_XFERINFOFUNCTION.html)

> **Unknown/unused argument values passed to the callback will be set to zero** (like if you only download data, the upload size will remain 0). **Many times the callback will be called one or more times first, before it knows the data sizes** so a program must be made to handle that.

If the callback is *never* giving you non-zero values during a download, then either:

1. there is a bug in libcurl (less likely)
2. libcurl *simply doesn't know* the sizes (more likely), such as if the download is encoded in such a way that prevents calculating the sizes effectively.

Comment: if it downloads data, at least the number of downloaded bytes should be increasing...

Comment: @DanielStenberg one would think so, yes.